# Unselecting rows in a Simple Multi Listbox stil Leaves ".ItemsSelected.Count = 1"

Tags: ms-access, listbox, vba, ms-access-2013

I have a simple multiselect listbox that keeps the selected count = 1 even after I deselect the all of the rows - it keeps a dotted line on the row even though its not black, I need this listbox to zero out when something isn't black, what am I doing wrong, is this normal?  How do I get back to zero when nothing is "technically" selected?

Comment: I am unable to recreate your issue. You can download a sample database [here](http://wikisend.com/download/690074/ListBoxTest.accdb) that contains a test form. There may be some difference between my (very simple) event code and yours that could explain the difference in behaviour.